# Qt : Update Multiple values on a Button Click

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am facing a problem regarding Signals and Slots mechanism of Qt. The core of the problem is here :

My application consists of 2 classes:

**MainGUI** : this class has all the core functionality of the app, and has some variables which store values relevant to the app.

**Preferences** : This class is used to draw and show a Settings panel, and has line-edit fields for updating the variables in MainGUI (using Signal-Slot mechanism)

Currently, i have connected them as follows:

```
Preferences *Pref;
MainGUI *M;
.
.
.
connect(Pref, SIGNAL(pref_varAChanged(QString)), M, SLOT(setVarA(QString)));
connect(Pref, SIGNAL(pref_varBChanged(QString)), M, SLOT(setVarB(QString)));
connect(Pref, SIGNAL(pref_varCChanged(QString)), M, SLOT(setVarC(QString)));
.
.
.
```

But, what this part does is that AS SOON AS the values are changed, the variables are updated, even though i have not click on 'APPLY' button (or an equivalent ACCEPT button...)

Please help me in implementing this functionality that the values A,B,C get updated only when a button, say, btn_accept is clicked...

*PS : I know this seems a very easy problem, and should be only a few lines long, but i've been trying to solve it and have been hitting the wall every time. I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction*

Comment: Extra Information :

Currently, i have written this code to implement the functionality mentioned earlier, but the values are actually updated BEFORE i click on ACCEPT button.

    `void Preferences::on_btn_accept_clicked()

    {

        emit pref_varAChanged(ui->lineEditA->text());

        emit pref_varBChanged(ui->lineEditB->text());

        emit pref_varCChanged(ui->lineEditC->text());

    }`

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you fully, but why don't you hook up the button signal to the slots, instead of the signal emitted by the text boxes?

Comment: why don't you try to emit one signal with three QString parameters which are from QLineEdits when btn_accept is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems i have figured out the problem.
It was simply a matter of emitting the 'variableChanged' signals when the ACCEPT button was clicked. This would update the variables in the MainGUI class.

It seems I had found the solution (read my comment), but I had misread the output my program gave, thus I had not realized that I had solved the problem until much later.

Thank you all for your comments. I'm sorry that this turned out to be such a waste of time.

Regards,

Harsh